# Convert NSDate to long format string and back again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

How would I convert an NSDate into a string like this:

```
Monday, November 22, 2010
```

.. and then back again into an NSDate?

Answer (score 6):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Something like:

```
NSDate *date=//...;
;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
//....
NSDate *newDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

There are more details I'm not covering, such as the Locale issues and whatnot, but this should get you going

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, especially `stringFromDate` and `dateFromString`. The link has good examples.